# Functional equations with 3 variables

Tags: functional-equations

What are the general solutions of the functional equations?

$$
f(x,y)+f(y,z)=\frac{1}{f(x,z)}
$$

$$
f(x,y)f(y,z)f(x,z)=1
$$

Comment: Are they independent, or supposed to be satisfied simultaneously?

Comment: They are independent, it is not a system of equations.

Comment: Well that ruins my answer. :-(

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming the variables are real.

For the first, setting $x=y=z$ gives $2f(x,x)=\frac 1{f(x,x)}$, so $f(x,x)=\pm\frac {\sqrt 2}2$

As Ivan Loh points out, the sign choice must be the same for all $x$:
$\quad$$y=z$ gives $f(x,z)+f(z,z)=\frac1f{(x,z)}$
$\quad$$x=y$ gives $f(x,x)+f(x,z)=\frac 1{f(x,z)}$
$\quad$so $f(x,x)=f(z,z).$

Assume $f(x,x)=\frac {\sqrt 2}2$:
$\quad$Setting $x=z$ gives $f(x,y)+f(y,x)=\sqrt 2$
$\quad$Setting $y=z$ gives $f(x,z)+\frac {\sqrt 2}2 = \frac 1{f(x,z)}$
$\quad$This has solutions $f(x,z)=\frac {\sqrt 2}2, -\sqrt 2$
$\quad$But only the first satisfies the original equation

Now if $f(x,x)=-\frac{\sqrt 2}2$
$\quad$Setting $x=z$ gives $f(x,y)+f(y,x)=-\sqrt 2$
$\quad$Setting $y=z$ gives $f(x,z)-\frac {\sqrt 2}2 = \frac 1{f(x,z)}$
$\quad$This has solutions $f(x,z)=-\frac {\sqrt 2}2, \sqrt 2$
$\quad$But only the first solves the original equation

**So $f(x,y)$ is the same for all $x,y$ and is $\pm \frac {\sqrt 2}2$**

For the second, setting $x=y=z$ gives $f(x,x)=1$
Setting $x=z$ we get $f(x,y)f(y,x)=1$ or $f(x,y)=\frac 1{f(y,x)}$
Setting $x=y$ we have $f(x,z)^2=1$
So $f(x,y)=\pm 1$ for all $x,y$

As Hagen von Eitzen points out, we can divide the reals into two equivalence classes in any way we want (including one of them empty).  Let $a,b$ be representatives of the two classes.  We have $f(a,a)=f(b,b)=1, f(a,b)=f(b,a)=-1$

Comment: Why can't $f(x,z)=-1$?

Comment: @vadim123:  for the second?  because then $f(x,x)^3$ would equal $-1$

Comment: You've proved that $f(x,z)^2=1$ for all $x,z$.  Perhaps this is sometimes 1, sometimes -1.  In those cases where $x=z$, it's 1, but maybe for other cases -1.

Comment: @vadim123:  good point.  It applies to the first as well.  I'll think on it.

Comment: Write $x\sim y$ if $f(x,y)=1$. Then you've shown that $\sim$ is reflexive and symmetric. As it is also transitive (by the original equation), $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. It cannot have more than two equivalence classes, but any equivalence relation with (at most) two classes solves the original equation.

Comment: @vadim123:  in the first, the $x=z$ line proves the claim that $f(x,y)=\frac {\sqrt 2}2$, the root $-\sqrt 2$ is not allowed.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, a sum of two elements $\in\{\frac{\sqrt 2}2,-\sqrt 2\}$ that produces $\sqrt 2$ msut be $\frac{\sqrt 2}2+\frac{\sqrt 2}2$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen:  I realized that immediately and deleted.  I have incorporated your comment in your answer.  Thanks.

Comment: For the first, $f(x, y)=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \, \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ is also a solution. This solution was missed because in your second line, $2f(x, x)=\frac{1}{f(x, x)}$ gives $f(x, x)=\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, instead of just $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Comment: @IvanLoh:  correct.  That ruins a lot.  I'll work on it

Comment: Fortunately, this can easily be worked around: $y=z$ gives $f(x, z)+f(z, z)=\frac{1}{f(x, z)}$, and $x=y$ gives $f(x, x)+f(x, z)=\frac{1}{f(x, z)}$ so $f(x, x)=f(z, z)$.

Answer (score 1):

Under the false assumption that they need to both hold,

From the first equation, $f$ is never zero.  From the second equation, $f(x,y)f(y,z)=\frac{1}{f(x,z)}$; combining with the first we get $$f(x,y)+f(y,z)=f(x,y)f(y,z)$$

Taking $x=y=z$ we get $2f(x,x)=f(x,x)^2$; since $f(x,x)\neq 0$ we have $f(x,x)=2$ for all $x$.  Taking $x=y$ we get $2+f(y,z)=2f(y,z)$ so $f(y,z)=2$ for all $y,z$.  But this doesn't satisfy the second equation, so there are no solutions.

Answer (score -1):

There are infinitely many(whose cardinality is $2^\Bbb R$)
solutions $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ of the simple functional equation
$$
f(x)^2=1.
$$
Let $A$ be an arbitrary subset of $\Bbb R$. Then,
$f(x)=1$ for $x\in A$, $f(x)=-1$ for $x\in A^c$ 
are the solutions of the equation.

Therefore, the above proof(by Millikan) makes no sense.

Comment: I would suggest that the (version of the) proof (that you responded to) made sense, at least to two readers.  It was incorrect.  A better approach would be to leave this as a comment to that effect, or to write up the correct proof fully.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't know the approach other ways. I agree that his proof will give some idea for a complete proof.